# SFML Error loading font under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, fonts, sfml

I've been trying to develop a cross-platform application for Windows and Linux using SFML. Everything's been going fine so far, except that the Windows version cannot seem to load fonts. I have no issues under Linux however.
I did my research and made sure the file was in place, according to where I was executing from, but sf::Font::loadFromFile still returns false.

Here's the code:

```
sf::Font _font;
sf::Text _text;

if (!(_font.loadFromFile("resources/fonts/arial.ttf")))
{
    std::cerr << "Error loading font '" + font + "'" << std::endl;
    return;
}
_text.setFont(_font);
```

Do you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm using SFML 2.3, linking statically.

Update: the loadFromFile methods doesn't work either for textures. I can check programmatically that the files are in place, and opening them with ifstreams works fine, but SFML cannot seem to access them.

Comment: Try to use the absolutely path to be sure that your file has been found

Comment: On a side note, you don't need the additional brackets following the `!` symbol (ie, `if (!(_font.loadFromFile("resources/fonts/arial.ttf")))` can be simplified to `if (!_font.loadFromFile("resources/fonts/arial.ttf"))`

Comment: Trying the absolute path unfortunately doesn't fix the issue... I checked the file was there using GetCurrentDirectory and such, but nothing gives

Comment: Did you check with another font?

Comment: I have, and the issue was still there unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, as usual my fault: I was using the release version of the library, but my VS project was in Debug!

Comment: Thanks I had the same problem. This problem sucks because debugging doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Check to make sure your file is in the correct directory and make sure the spelling is exact as well. Usually this is the most common source of error.

Comment: As I said in the comments, already checked... And it works in Unix, considering my project tree is set up with CMake spelling is the same in both versions...